# Angular 2 - Switch between PathLocationProvider and HashLocationProvider

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, browser-history, html5-history

I was given the impression HTML5 routes via `PathLocationProvider` does not work with IE9. Unfortunately, I need to support IE9 and above for now. Does anyone know if `PathLocationProvider` works with IE9? I saw a GitHub discussion that there may have been a workaround implemented: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6506.

If I am stuck using `HashLocationProvider`, is there a way I can look to see if the browser supports `pushState` via the history API and switch between implementations at start up? I saw people using Modernizer to do this in JavaScript/AngularJS, but I can't figure out how to do this in TypeScript/Angular 2. Will switching implementations at start up cause any issues?